# Installing a color scheme for Vim

Tags: vim

I was wondering if someone could assist me in installing a color scheme for VIM? I literally have spent all day yesterday and this morning trying to figure it out. I am using a shell-client (ubuntu) to access my school's unix server. I will post a link to what I am trying to install and thank you in advance for your assistance:

https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-gotham

Comment: You need a Vim plugin manager.  Once you have that, color schemes are installed like any other plugin, there isn't anything special about them.

Comment: in case you didn't know about: vim.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions in the `README.md` seems very clear to me:

> If you don't use a plugin manager just copy the content of `vim/colors/` to `~/.vim/colors`.

(if you get the repository with `git`, like I did, the directory to copy from will not lie in a `vim` directory, but in `vim-gotham`).

I made a test installation of the color scheme that worked:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git clone git@github.com:whatyouhide/vim-gotham.git
$ mkdir ~/.vim/colors
$ cp vim-gotham/colors/* ~/.vim/colors
```

If you want the "themes":

```
$ mkdir ~/.vim/autoload
$ cp -r vim-gotham/autoload/* ~/.vim/autoload
```

Cleanup:

```
$ cd
$ rm -rf test
```

Then I can use the command `:colorscheme gotham` in Vim (or use `colorscheme gotham` in my `~/.vimrc` file).

Can't say anything about the themes though. I use plain Vim, default everything.